# Xcode 6 crashes on OS X 10.10 with with Exception name: IBAssertionFailure

Tags: ios, crash, interface-builder, xcode6, osx-mavericks

It was working fine when i was copying and paste uitableview cells inside  interface builder. But on next day when i start Xcode it crashed with report,

> Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. If you choose to file a crash report or Radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.
>
> Exception name: IBAssertionFailure
>   Exception reason: ASSERTION FAILURE: containingTableView
>   Reason:     Any table view cell being added to a layout engine should be contained in a table view in order to get the correct metrics

I tried to `empty cache` by following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/1556386. I also tried to `fresh reinstall Xcode 6.1.1` but nothing sort out the problem. 
Exception details are,

```
Process:               Xcode [3408]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1.1 (6611)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6611000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       810788292
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [3408]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-01-30 12:26:14.681 +0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        835265AB-3F12-806B-3EAE-821EB008717D


Time Awake Since Boot: 3800 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A2008a
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-6254/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBAbstractMessageChannelInterfaceBuilderToolProxy.m:40
Details:  Failed to compute auto layout status IBLayoutConstraint, IBUILabel, IBUITableViewCell, and IBUITableViewCellContentView.

Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. If you choose to file a crash report or Radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: IBAssertionFailure
Exception reason: ASSERTION FAILURE: containingTableView
Reason:     Any table view cell being added to a layout engine should be contained in a table view in order to get the correct metrics
File:       /SourceCache/IBSimulatorComponents/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-6247/SimulatorComponents/IBCocoaTouchTool/WidgetIntegration/IBCTTUITableViewCellIntegration.m:227
Method:     -[UITableViewCell(IBCocoaTouchToolIntegration) ibEffectiveViewToPlaceInLayoutEngineWindow]
Exception backtrace: 
  0. CoreFoundation           0x000000010a6baf1d __exceptionPreprocess
  1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x00000001093a1bb7 objc_exception_throw
  2. CoreFoundation           0x000000010a6bab79 -[NSException raise]
  3. ???                      0x0000000106e94e73 [UITableViewCell ibEffectiveViewToPlaceInLayoutEngineWindow]
  4. ???                      0x0000000106e9bc88 [UIView ibWindowForUpdatingConstraints:]
  5. ???                      0x0000000106e909db [NSObject ibPlaceInWindowPositioningAndSizingIfNeeded:during:]
  6. ???                      0x0000000106e9caae [UIView ibPlaceInWindowPositioningAndSizingIfNeeded:during:]
  7. ???                      0x0000000106e7b697 [IBCocoaTouchToolArbitrationUnit _ensureRootObjectIsInWindowDuring:]
  8. ???                      0x0000000106e7ba60 [IBCocoaTouchToolArbitrationUnit computeStatusFromEngine:]
  9. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x0000000108a4f82b -[IBAutolayoutArbitrationUnit computeStatus]
 10. ???                      0x0000000106e797a5 [IBCocoaTouchTool computeAutolayoutStatusForRequest:document:]
 11. IBFoundation             0x0000000108bc18ef __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]_block_invoke
 12. IBFoundation             0x0000000108bc1686 -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]
 13. IBFoundation             0x0000000108bc1350 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke
 14. libdispatch.dylib        0x000000010dcb6af4 _dispatch_client_callout
 15. libdispatch.dylib        0x000000010dca3e95 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke
 16. libdispatch.dylib        0x000000010dcb6af4 _dispatch_client_callout
 17. libdispatch.dylib        0x000000010dca2265 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
 18. CoreFoundation           0x000000010a622fe9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
 19. CoreFoundation           0x000000010a5e5eeb __CFRunLoopRun
 20. CoreFoundation           0x000000010a5e5486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
 21. Foundation               0x0000000108f5eb42 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
 22. IBFoundation             0x0000000108ba0955 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:]
 23. IBFoundation             0x0000000108ba0a2f -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingSocket:]
 24. IBFoundation             0x0000000108ba0cf2 +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main]
 25. ???                      0x0000000106eabe90 [IBViewRenderer .cxx_destruct]
 26. libdyld.dylib            0x000000010dce7145 start
```

Comment: See my Answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

There was error in Storyboard file , i simply delete the Main.Storyboard file from Finder and than open Xcode. Xcode was than running normally.